How do people effectively test the V3 Capctha in the checkout
We run Cloudflare, but as an additional layer of security, as there have been several scripted card attacks found in the Worldpay logs, it’s been decided to add a captcha.
V3 is the obvious choice for checkout as it’s unobtrusive
I have also added a v2 invisible to the account login
I’m aware recaptcha is notoriously hard to debug, we use Cypress to run automated tests, however - they return as a “safe” user scoring 0.1 every time
The threshold is set at 0.5
How can I identify as a nefarious bot - every time, so that I can test correctly whether the captcha is stopping bots and is an effective additional layer of security.
